# Hot to Code Custom Font in HTML/CSS to display properly on other computers

Tags: html, css, fonts

I need help please, I'm using a Custom font for my new website design which I had to do download. On my computer website looks good with this new font. Unfortunately it is not the case for any other user who did not download this custom font.
pls see: www.vanessawiacekwebs.com

I have tried use Font Face but it does not work and I do not know why ?

Font:  Marathon II; http://ufonts.com/q177208

Thank you,

Comment: Please post your CSS code to your question.

Comment: Click the edit button beneath the tags in your question. Edit your question by adding the CSS, highlight it and then select "Code Snippet" from the text editor.

Comment: You're incorrectly linking to the font source. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're incorrectly directly linking to the font source.

## Your incorrect CSS code:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: Marathon II;
    src: url(http://ufonts.com/q177208);
}
```

You need to download the fonts, upload them to your file directory and then use the `@font-face` rule to link to font files.

A multitude of beginner's tutorials exist online: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way and a hard way.  The easy way is to use Google Fonts.  Web Fonts were a huge PITA, and Google Fonts makes it easy.

https://www.google.com/fonts

There are other options, but after 20 years of web development, this is the only solution I use.